# Proxy for docker under windows 10 only works for http, but not for https

Tags: docker, https, proxy

for quite a while I try to build a Dockerfile, but get therefore I need necessary not packages from Nvidia, which are fetched from a https link.

Since this I have to use proxy I set the following variables in the dockerfile:

```
ENV http_proxy http://proxy:0000
ENV https_proxy https://user:password@proxy:0000
```

If I do not add a user and a password to the https proxy, then I get the HTTP 407 error , which means an authentication failure. If I include a use and password I get the following error:

```
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages [801 kB]
Ign:6 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  InRelease
  .
  .
  .
Ign:24 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Packages
Ign:16 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Packages
Ign:24 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Packages
Ign:16 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Packages
Ign:24 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Packages
Ign:16 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Packages
Ign:24 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Packages
Err:16 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Packages
      server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
Err:24 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Packages
      server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
   Fetched 15.7 MB in 3s (3984 kB/s)
    Reading package lists...
    W: The repository 'https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Release' does not have a Release file.
    W: The repository 'https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Release' does not have a Release file.
    E: Failed to fetch https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/Packages  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
    E: Failed to fetch https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/Packages  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
    E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

So the proxy for http works, but not for https. I guess it is something with the ssl certificates as metnioned in the rror, but I can not find anything useful for this topic. Btw. this is a windows issue, obviously under Linux everything worked fine.

Comment: You need to have a copy of the root CA certificate that was used to sign the certificate chain that the website returns when communicating using TLS. Firefox has an open-source list of certificates that can be used for this purpose.

Comment: what happens if you do `https_proxy http://proxy:0000`

Comment: @Zannith I get HTTP 407 error

Comment: you did have it as `https://proxy`, I'm wondering because I made that mistake with our proxy when both `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` should point to the same `http://proxy:0000` or perhaps `http://user:password@proxy:port`

Comment: @Zannith yeah, I read it  and tryed every possible configurations, but unfortunately it does not work. I try to get the TLF certificates as mentioned Jonathan Gray. However, it is difficult, if I can not install anything.